# XMLHttpRequest in Ajax and PHP

Tags: ajax

In internet explorer we can create the object of ActiveXObject like follows

```
xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async="false";
xmlDoc.load("note_error.xml");
```

It is possible to use the xmlDoc.load("note_error.xml"); for the object of XMLHttpRequest in other browsers.If no,any other substitute for this method when we use XMLHttpRequest.Please help...am using firefox as my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmlDoc.async="false";
```

That's not doing what you think. `async` is a boolean property. When you assign the *string* `"false"` to it, you're getting the value `true`, because all non-empty strings are truthy.

> It is possible to use the xmlDoc.load("note_error.xml"); for the object of XMLHttpRequest in other browsers.

Yes, in fact that's what you should be doing in IE too. There is no reason to use `XMLDOM` to fetch an XML Document; XMLHttpRequest can do that fine and it's much more widely supported.

```
var xhr= window.XMLHttpRequest? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHttp');
xhr.async= false;
xhr.open('GET', 'note_error.xml');
xhr.send();
var doc= xhr.responseXML;
```

If you *do* need an `XMLDOM`-like object in other browsers, it's called `new DOMParser`, but it's not as widely-supported as `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

the activeX 'concept' is only in Internet Explorer. All other browser implement a similar, but more or less standard version.

http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_browsers.asp

that shows you how to create an xmlhttp object in 'any' browser.